# How can I solve this ORDER BY in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table structured like this:

```
ID    NAME     SURNAME      EXTRA       TYPE
______________________________________________

1     MARIO     ROSSI       RED          10
2     MARCO     VERDI       YELLOW       10
3     GIANNI    BLU         TEACHER      20
4     LUCA      BLU         STUDENT      20 
5     LUCA      ROSSI       GREEN        10 
6     MARIA     GIALLA      10/08/05     30  
7     MARTA     ROSA        11/01/79     30
8     FRANCO    NERO        BARMAN       20
9     MARY      NERI        05/09/88     30
10    MAX       BLU         06/08/98     30
```

Now I need to order the query by name, surname and (extra[DESC] where type=30), so with this 3rd condition I mean that I would arrange all extra data where type is 30 in descending order:

```
....
6     MARIA     GIALLA      10/08/05     30  
10    MAX       BLU         06/08/98     30
9     MARY      NERI        05/09/88     30
7     MARTA     ROSA        11/01/79     30
....
```

So I've tried this:

```
select * from my_table order by name, surname, if(my_table.type=30, extra desc, extra asc)
```

but it gives me an Sql Error.

Thanks for your support.

Thanks to other programmers, and in according to my data, I solved in this way:  ORDER BY name, surname, if(TYPE=30, STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y %H.%i'), null) DESC

Comment: would you mind sharing the exact error you get?

Comment: Also, I don't understand how the desired result set conforms to the requirement. Do you want the results that are dates (i.e. type 30) to be stored in descending order of date? If so, consider storing dates as if they were proper date data types (i.e. yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: It's rather non-sensical to order by date when all combinations of name and surname are unique.

Comment: Olli- Mysql gives me a general Error.

Comment: Strawberry- Yes, I desire have the result in date type descending but the first 2 conditions are By name, surname

Comment: @Strawberry, ignore the fact of SAMPLE data is all unique.  What would happen IF MILLIONS of records and there were duplicates of name/surname.  Don't limit your thinking to just what is displayed...

Comment: @DRapp Thank you. We don't need millions of rows, a data set of just 10 rows is more than capable of adequately explaining the problem - just not THESE 10 rows.

Comment: @Strawberry, I guess you just dont get it.  I was indicating that the PRODUCTION data could have millions of records, not just 10 here.  And what if duplicate entries for same name/surname with multiple dates.  Is data normalized for distinct person that have common name?  Who is who does not appear to be any consideration of the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabletest
order by 
  CASE WHEN type <> 30 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  CASE WHEN type <> 30 THEN Name END,
  CASE WHEN type <> 30 THEN Surname END,
  CASE WHEN type = 30 THEN STR_TO_DATE(extra,'%m/%d/%Y') ELSE 0 END DESC
```

this will order the results as:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: how can I provide a demo?

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud but also this solution can't help me: the order of EXTRA is casual and not for decr date :/

Comment: Mahmoud the result you posted is what I need! Unfortunatly I tried to reproduce it on my database but the order of the last set (Type=60) is random and not by date DESC.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, sincerely in db the date is rapresented as: 18/03/2015 10.30 but I don't think the problem is that, I replaced the code in this way:  CASE WHEN TYPE= 30 THEN STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y H.i') ELSE 0 END DESC

Comment: When I try to conver the string (EXTRA) in date (only for those who have TYPE 30) with: STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y H.i')  I receive this error: Incorrect datetime value: '10/01/2014 17.00' for function str_to_date.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @FrancescoL. - I used the format `%m/%d/%Y` based on the data sample you posted, for values like `10/01/2014 17.00` you should choose format like this `%m/%d/%Y %H.%i` see all possible formats here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @FrancescoL. - Also the query handles the order for the case type = 30 not for type = 60.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, yes it was an error stamp 60 and not 30... but my error was here: %m/%d/%Y %H.%i...... I forgot to insert % symbol near H and i, so the right solution to my question is: ORDER BY condition1, conditon2, IF(TYPE=30, STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y %H.%i'), null) DESC.    Now, since I'm a newbie in this forum, I ask you how can I put in evidence this solution so other people who have my same problem could read my post and find the right solution? Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: Thanks! I hope this post will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :-

```
ORDER BY 
IF(type='30', extra, 0) DESC,
IF(type !='30', extra, 0) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but this solution doesn't work :/

Comment: Aside from needing the name/surname before the extra, you were on track with my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

More usefully, consider the following:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

    CREATE TABLE my_table
    (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL     
    ,SURNAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL      
    ,EXTRA VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL      
    ,TYPE INT NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
    ( 1,'MARIO','ROSSI','RED','10'),
    ( 2,'MARCO','VERDI','YELLOW','10'),
    ( 3,'GIANNI','BLU','TEACHER','20'),
    ( 4,'LUCA','BLU','STUDENT','20'),
    ( 5,'LUCA','ROSSI','GREEN','10'),
    ( 6,'MARIA','GIALLA','2005/08/10','30'),
    ( 7,'MARTA','ROSA','1979/01/11','30'),
    ( 8,'FRANCO','NERO','BARMAN','20'),
    ( 9,'MARY','NERI','1988/09/05','30'),
    (10,'MAX','BLU','1998/08/06','30'),
    (11,'MARIO','ROSSI','PLUMBER','20'),
    (12,'MARCO','VERDI','TAILOR','20'),
    (13,'GIANNI','BLU','YELLOW','10'),
    (14,'LUCA','BLU','BLUE','10'),
    (15,'LUCA','ROSSI','BAKER','20'),
    (16,'MARIO','ROSSI','2004/08/10','30'),
    (17,'MARCO','VERDI','1978/01/11','30'),
    (18,'FRANCO','NERO','RED','10'),
    (19,'FRANCO','NERO','1987/09/05','30'),
    (20,'MARIA','GIALLA','1995/08/06','30');

    SELECT name
         , surname
         , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 10 THEN extra END) colour
         , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 20 THEN extra END) occupation
         , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 30 THEN extra END) date
      FROM my_table
     GROUP 
        BY name
         , surname
     ORDER 
        BY name
         , surname
         , extra
         , type
         , date DESC;
+--------+---------+--------+------------+------------+
| name   | surname | colour | occupation | date       |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+------------+
| FRANCO | NERO    | RED    | BARMAN     | 1987/09/05 |
| GIANNI | BLU     | YELLOW | TEACHER    | NULL       |
| LUCA   | BLU     | BLUE   | STUDENT    | NULL       |
| LUCA   | ROSSI   | GREEN  | BAKER      | NULL       |
| MARCO  | VERDI   | YELLOW | TAILOR     | 1978/01/11 |
| MARIA  | GIALLA  | NULL   | NULL       | 2005/08/10 |
| MARIO  | ROSSI   | RED    | PLUMBER    | 2004/08/10 |
| MARTA  | ROSA    | NULL   | NULL       | 1979/01/11 |
| MARY   | NERI    | NULL   | NULL       | 1988/09/05 |
| MAX    | BLU     | NULL   | NULL       | 1998/08/06 |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+------------+
```

You can join a result like this (or actually a much simpler alternative - but I'll stick with this for now) back onto the original table to order the results as you'd like. I've added in the STR_TO_DATE function just for reference. Obviously it's unnecessary here, and very slightly different from how it would need to be in your version...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , y.date
   FROM my_table x
   LEFT
   JOIN
      ( SELECT name
             , surname
             , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 30 THEN extra END) date
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY name
             , surname
      ) y
     ON y.name = x.name
    AND y.surname = x.surname
  ORDER
     BY x.name
      , x.surname
      , STR_TO_DATE(y.date,'%Y/%m/%d') DESC;

+----+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+
| ID | NAME   | SURNAME | EXTRA      | TYPE | date       |
+----+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+
| 18 | FRANCO | NERO    | RED        |   10 | 1987/09/05 |
| 19 | FRANCO | NERO    | 1987/09/05 |   30 | 1987/09/05 |
|  8 | FRANCO | NERO    | BARMAN     |   20 | 1987/09/05 |
| 13 | GIANNI | BLU     | YELLOW     |   10 | NULL       |
|  3 | GIANNI | BLU     | TEACHER    |   20 | NULL       |
| 14 | LUCA   | BLU     | BLUE       |   10 | NULL       |
|  4 | LUCA   | BLU     | STUDENT    |   20 | NULL       |
| 15 | LUCA   | ROSSI   | BAKER      |   20 | NULL       |
|  5 | LUCA   | ROSSI   | GREEN      |   10 | NULL       |
| 17 | MARCO  | VERDI   | 1978/01/11 |   30 | 1978/01/11 |
|  2 | MARCO  | VERDI   | YELLOW     |   10 | 1978/01/11 |
| 12 | MARCO  | VERDI   | TAILOR     |   20 | 1978/01/11 |
|  6 | MARIA  | GIALLA  | 2005/08/10 |   30 | 2005/08/10 |
| 20 | MARIA  | GIALLA  | 1995/08/06 |   30 | 2005/08/10 |
| 11 | MARIO  | ROSSI   | PLUMBER    |   20 | 2004/08/10 |
| 16 | MARIO  | ROSSI   | 2004/08/10 |   30 | 2004/08/10 |
|  1 | MARIO  | ROSSI   | RED        |   10 | 2004/08/10 |
|  7 | MARTA  | ROSA    | 1979/01/11 |   30 | 1979/01/11 |
|  9 | MARY   | NERI    | 1988/09/05 |   30 | 1988/09/05 |
| 10 | MAX    | BLU     | 1998/08/06 |   30 | 1998/08/06 |
+----+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I have a field named "extra" which contains date, char, int ecc.... and I need to add at the end of conditions that already exists ( in ORDER BY ) this: show me all records (in DESC way) where  the type field is 60 ( we know that the field=60 is a date in this format 10/05/2015 15.50). thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @FrancescoL. You can join this result back to the original query to order the core data set in the correct manner.

Comment: I discover that probably the problem is that I have the field EXTRA as TEXT (I can't change this)  so, when in this field there is a date mysql consider it as a string and it order those strings. So I need to convert before the text (in this case 10/08/2015 13.45) in a format date with STR_TO_DATE and then maybe I'll be able to make the order by correctly. Right? Or there is a simplest way to resove it?

Comment: You should store dates as dates (i.e. YYYY/DD/MM) - even where you can't take advantage of the DATE data type. Really, even when using an EAV model such as this, you should still store data in its respective data types, so all integers go in an INTs column, dates go in a DATEs column, and strings go in a VARCHAR column. If it was me, I would construct a separate table for each data type.

Comment: Well, then you've answered your own question ;-)

Comment: Yes. str_to_date is your only option.

Comment: Yes, I tried this way: CASE  
 WHEN TYPE = 60  THEN  STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y H.i')  ELSE 0  END DESC but I received this error: Incorrect datetime value: '21/10/2013 12.00' for function str_to_date

Comment: @Strawberrie, your answer gave me the right way to solve the problem. I forgot to insert % symbol near H and i, so the right solution to my question is: ORDER BY condition1, conditon2, IF(TYPE=30, STR_TO_DATE(EXTRA,'%d/%m/%Y %H.%i'), null) DESC.    Now, since I'm a newbie, I ask you how can I put in evidence this solution so other people who have my same problem could read my post and find the right solution? Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: You could write your own answer, incorporating the best bits of the other answers provided, and accept that as the answer. You should give points though to the answers that you think have been helpful. Of course, I think my answer is the only sensible response to this question posted to date, and so it should be the accepted answer, but I suppose I would think that.

Comment: Yes, I tried to click on "Right Sign" Green.... but nothing will happen... maybe I'm the owner of the post so I can't check myself or maybe I can't check (Accept) 2 answers in the same post. Also I don't know why my question got -1 star at the top of this post...  :/

Comment: Yo ucan only ACCEPT one answer. As for the downvote, that was me. I downvoted because you failed to provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements, and because neither the data set nor the result set provided were adequately representative of the problem. So, in fact, I still don't really know what you're looking for - and I even suspect that both my answer and the accepted answer are wrong (although for different reasons)

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought it was clearly what I was looking for. Also the way you gave helped me to find the solution.

Comment: well there is my support. If someone helps a lot @FrancescoL., then reward them with the up arrow. That's how we roll here. Oh, you can't, you dont have 15 rep yet. Just sayin

Comment: yes, I want to thank them with an up arrow but I can't :/